# Print/show a user's password in mysql CLI

Tags: mysql, database

I use Ubuntu server 16.04 (xenial) with Mysql 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20 (x86_64) with EditLine wrapper.

How to print/output the password of a particular mysql user in mysql CLI?

I don' ask how to change it:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'coolest_user_ever'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD_CAME_HERE');
```

I ask about just printing it's current password, output it to the screen, somehow after I've logged in as root with `mysql -u root -p[ROOT_PASSWORD]`.

Comment: Passwords in MySQL are hashed. You can set a new one, but you cannot retrieve it - it is one way. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function for details.

Comment: select `host`, `user`, `password` from mysql.user where `user` = 'user_name' and `host` = 'your_host'. Note that this only show the hashed password and can only be done prior to MySQL 5.7. In MySQL 5.7 and newer, the `password` column is someway hidden or not shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a password hash is to make that process impossible or at least difficult enough to be impractical. You really can't reverse the process, the best you can hope for is to find a string that hashes to the same thing.

If someone's lost their password, reset it to something else. Don't ever presume you can recover it. If you can, your security model is fatally flawed.